# await function failing, is a babel compile thing missing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I've just taken over a project from a disgruntled developer who thinks he's the best thing since sliced bread.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj4RB.png)

He swears his code was running on the last commit... although, I get problems in an async/await. I vaguely remember having similar problems when not supporting the right version of babel, but that was years back. The project is created with `create-react-app`.

Here's the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "jest": {
    "transform": {}
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@makerdao/multicall": "^0.11.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.8",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bignumber.js": "^9.0.1",
    "bip32": "^2.0.6",
    "bip38": "^3.1.1",
    "bip39": "^3.0.2",
    "bitcoinjs-lib": "^5.2.0",
    "bs58check": "^2.1.2",
    "ci": "^1.0.0",
    "fake-indexeddb": "^3.1.2",
    "highcharts": "^8.2.2",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.0.0",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3",
    "json-bigint": "^1.0.0",
    "json-bignumber": "^1.0.2",
    "keccak256": "^1.0.2",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "puppeteer": "^5.5.0",
    "qrcode-svg": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "secp256k1": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5",
    "web3": "^1.3.0",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --verbose",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "plugin:react/recommended"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ansi-regex": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Promise != Function. I think instead of `await f()`, it should be `await f` but I might be wrong.

Comment: Strangely, that part of code was written two months ago, and a static build of the site is working since a couple of days... so there must be something else wrong

Comment: Maybe! We can't tell unless we see some actual code. Add code. Then add the error. And not the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a promise to the function, and promise is not a function. You should do instead: `await f` and not execute it by `await f()` since the promise just needs to be called and not to be executed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't the problem, the old developer managed to build and deploy the static site recently, and that piece of code was written 2 months ago.

Comment: @Webel how is this not a problem? That's exactly what the error states. _f is not a function._

Comment: Yes... I did get that, I trusted the other developer wholeheartedly thou. Turns out he lied.